# Extract content from file between two same pattern

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, awk, sed

I have a log file for which I need portions belonging to a particular type of log. It can be of multiple lines.
I cannot post the log file here directly but it is of below format:

```
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message2
line 5
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE2 random-message3
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE3 random-message4
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message5
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message6
line 10
line 11
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE7 random-message7
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE8 random-message9
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE9 random-message10
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message11
```

I need the output to be:

```
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message2
line 5
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message5
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message6
line 10
line 11
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message11
```

I tried using sed but using ' Thread-MESSAGE1' as both the start as well as end pattern did not work if there are two consecutive logs with 'MESSAGE1' key. 
I thought of using negative lookup ahead using Perl(which worked), but unfortunately I cannot use Perl and neither 'sed' nor 'awk' supports negative lookup ahead in pattern. 
Recently I was trying with the following 'sed' pattern:

```
tac source_file.log | sed -n '{/<date-format> Thread-/!H; /<date-format> Thread-/{H;d;x} /<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1/p; d;}' > test.log
```

The idea was to reverse output of test.log afterwards, but for adding curly braces after 'Thread-/{H;d;x}' I am getting 'extra characters after command' error.
Is there a better alternative? Or is there a way I can group commands using curly braces in sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -v kw='Thread-MESSAGE1' '$2 ~ /^Thread-/ {p = ($2 == kw)} p' file

<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message2
line 5
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message5
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message6
line 10
line 11
<date-format> Thread-MESSAGE1 random-message11
```

If this doesn't workout then I suggest you post more realistic sample data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have verified that this command works for the given file. But I just have one question, right now kw='Thread-MESSAGE1' is a constant string. Can it have regex as well?

Comment: If you want to pass in regex then inside the awk command use `$2 ~ kw` instead of `$2 == kw`